# reactjs- how to identify the line item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to delete a record onClick(how to identify which item/model is clicked and delete the data from the state). And Do I need a nameRecord created with React.createClass or is it enough to just use a function(does reactjs keep track of each record differently if I use createClass/just function).

```
var nameRecord = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e){
        alert('my name is'+this.props.data.name);
        this.destroy() // can I remove the record
    },
    render: function(){
        return <ol onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.data.name}</ol>
    }    
});
var people = [{"name":"king"},{"name":"Larry"}]
var NameList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { 
        data: people,
    };
  },
  render:function(){

    people = this.state.data.slice(0,5)
    return <ul>    
        List of Names - 
        {people.map(function(person){
            return <nameRecord data={person}>child</nameRecord>
        })}

      </ul>
      ;
  }

})
React.renderComponent(
  <NameList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
  )
```

Comment: is there a reason for requesting closing....

Comment: This tip from the React docs may help: http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React components don't destroy themselves. You'd propagate the event to the owner component or rather to the component that holds the data, e.g. as state. Then you'd modify the data and rerender the component.

For example:

```
var nameRecord = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e){
      // propagate event
      if (this.props.onDelete) {
        this.props.onDelete(this.props.data);
      }
    },
    render: function(){
      return <ol onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.data.name}</ol>
    }    
});

var people = [{"name":"king"},{"name":"Larry"}];

var NameList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { 
        data: people,
    };
  },
  onDelete: function(index) {
    // remove element and update state, which causes a rerender
    var data = this.state.data.slice()
       .splice(this.data.indexOf(person), 1);
    this.setState({data: data});
  },
  render: function(){

    var names = this.state.data.map(function(person){
      return (
        <nameRecord data={person} onDelete={this.onDelete} />
      );
    }.bind(this))

    return (
      <div>
        List of Names - 
        <ul>{names}</ul> 
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: Everyone seems to advise this method. Isn't there a way to get the target from the event object that is passed to the click handler?

Comment: is it not a lot of work to re render the whole list than just destroy itself/take care of itself at line item level... Also is there a better way other than index to generate unique id..so that delete at line item happens by these unique ids...

Comment: I updated the code to make it a bit better. It's the false conception that recreating the whole structure is too expensive. The real expensive work is updating the DOM, and React computes a minimal set of actions to perform to update the DOM. I.e. It will simply reuse existing DOM nodes if it can. If you experience performance issues, you should make use of a component's `shouldComponentUpdate` method, which controls whether a component as to rerender or not.

Comment: So this is a totally different  than backbone where if I am deleting a line, I would have a model id (unique id ) and I can just the delete the associated view/remove that dom element alone...rather creating the table again..so you have a table and a 100 lines, with react js If I delete 1 line or add 1 line, I would basically recreate the entire table..or am I missing something

Comment: BTW I saw you added index to identify each line..would it be nice to go with unique for each line...unless you are going with recreating each time..

Comment: @coool: Yeah, actually you have to add a unique `key` to each element in the array, otherwise React will complain. But since I don't know enough about your data, I cannot really suggest anything (you could do `key={person.name}`). The important part to understand is that `<nameRecord data={person} onDelete={this.onDelete} />` does not render the element. It simply creates a very light weight container. Then, when React is a about to render the elements, it compares them to the existing virtual DOM. If properly set up (e.g. with `shouldComponentUpdate`), React won't even call the render...

Comment: ... method and reuse what already exists. Maybe this will help you understand the process better: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html